# Remove Album Art from Lock Screen

Tags: lock-screens, 4.4-kitkat, album-art

How can I remove the album art from showing on my lock screen? I want my live wallpaper to show instead.

Edit: should have added device and ROM. Sorry first time on here. Using a Sprint GS3 with CM11 Nightlies.

Comment: Kindly add your device and ROM (if custom ROM) to help you further.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the music application you are using (probably Apollo in your case) is responsible for this. You might want to try a different one.

I just dug into Apollos source code and think I have found where it sets the album artwork. Check out [line 1377](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Apollo/blob/9d66567ae072083c53df5f64f501fcf80893811e/src/com/andrew/apollo/MusicPlaybackService.java#L1377) on Github.

`mRemoteControlClient.putBitmap(RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor.BITMAP_KEY_ARTWORK, albumArt);`

The way I see it, the call to [RemoteControlClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) is responsible for setting the album art and other things. So, the media player is responsible for your problem and unlike you find one that doesn't provide the album art to the `RemoteControlClient` you probably can't do much about it.

Comment: I am actually using Spotify. I imagined that it would have something to do with the actual lock screen code and not the application that is playing music.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in KitKat using the Xposed Framework with the AudioPrivacy module: http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.audio.privacy

Unfortunately, this does not work in Lollipop, because Xposed does not work on Lollipop. I wish the CyanogenMod team would just add an option to disable this to the Lockscreen settings. Maybe I will bug them about it.