# How can I disable album art on my lock screen?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, music-player, google-play-music

I'm not a big fan of my lock screen getting hijacked by whatever music app is currently playing. Is there a setting, app, or work around that can disable album art from being displayed on my lock screen? Preferably without rooting.

I'm using a Moto X Pure Edition running Nougat. I would prefer solutions that work for Google Play Music.

[Related](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61968/remove-album-art-from-lock-screen)

Comment: I'm not sure about any settings but you can use VLC as your music player and can disable lock screen cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play Music, since version 8.7, has a setting to enable/disable album arts on the lock screen.

1. Open Google Play Music, then open Settings.
2. In the Play back section, disable "Show album art on lock screen".

[image: IMG:]

The album art will now be shown next to the music buttons instead of taking over the whole screen when it is locked.

Note: Tested on versions 8.8 and 8.18.

Source: [Google Play Music v8.7 adds option to disable album art on the lock screen](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/02/26/google-play-music-v8-7-adds-option-disable-album-art-lock-screen-apk-download/)